# How to display video thumbnail with play button in center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, video

I am trying to play video from url in ios.So basically i am adding a `MPMoviePlayerController` view into the main view.So what i want i load the viewcontroller i should be able to see a VideoView with thumbnail of video & a play button image in center as we see in YouTube App. I know how can i get the video thubnail but is there any feature by which i can get play button image at center as part of thumbnail.

**Code for adding VideoView:**

```
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"];
    self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    CGRect movieFrame;
    movieFrame.size = self.videoView.frame.size;
    [self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame:movieFrame];
    [self.moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    [self.moviePlayerController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.videoView addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];
    [self.videoView bringSubviewToFront:self.moviePlayerController.view];
    [self.videoView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.moviePlayerController.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.videoView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0.0]];
    [self.videoView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.moviePlayerController.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.videoView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0.0]];
    [self.videoView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.moviePlayerController.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.videoView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0.0]];
    [self.videoView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.moviePlayerController.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.videoView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0.0]];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [self.moviePlayerController thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    [self.moviePlayerController play];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fullVideoScreen:)];
    singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.moviePlayerController.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

**Code for getting the thumbnail**

```
  NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                 initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    mp.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    mp.initialPlaybackTime = 0;
    mp.currentPlaybackTime = 05;
    // get the thumbnail
    UIImage *thumbnail = [mp thumbnailImageAtTime:2
                                       timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    self.videoView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:thumbnail];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set control sytle to MPMovieControlStyleNone, the player view won't show any control UI. You may need build you own control UI as you want. Hope this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Following code for the getting thumb of the video.

```
NSString *str = [[self.videoArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"vName"];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str] ;
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL]autorelease];
UIImage  *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:0.41 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
player = nil;
```

For Play button you need to add custom on uiview.

May this help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use video control style to none:

```
myPlayer.view.frame = videoView.bounds;
myPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

and now you can adding UIButton to center video view frame and control video with yourself.

```
[videoControllButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[videoControllButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playPauseClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

this is code from my old app, whitch solve this problem:

init tab to video player

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onPlayerTapped:)];
singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleFingerTap.delegate = self;
[myPlayer.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

and control tap from button:

```
bool videoIsPlaying = NO;
-(IBAction)playFromIcon:(id)sender{
    videoIsPlaying = TRUE;
    [videoControllButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myPlayer play];
    playIcon.hidden = YES;
}
```

on tap to player

```
-(void) onPlayerTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (videoIsPlaying == TRUE) {
         videoIsPlaying = FALSE;
         [videoControllButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [myPlayer pause];
         playIcon.hidden = NO;
    }else{
        videoIsPlaying = TRUE;
        [videoControllButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myPlayer play];
        playIcon.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

or tap to button to play pause...

```
-(IBAction)playPauseClick:(id)sender{
    if (videoIsPlaying == TRUE) {
        videoIsPlaying = FALSE;
        [videoControllButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myPlayer pause];
        playIcon.hidden = NO;
    }else{
        videoIsPlaying = TRUE;
        [videoControllButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myPlayer play];
        playIcon.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```